# How to use bouncycastle in java to generate a CSR with a subject alternative name

Tags: security, bouncycastle, csr

After a bunch of searching around,  I came up with the following:

```
        PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
            new X500Principal("CN=clustername"), publicKey);
        

        ASN1Encodable[] subjectAlternativeNames2 = new ASN1Encodable[] {
                new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, "clusteruid"),
                new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, "127.0.0.1")
        };
        DERSequence subjectAlternativeNamesExtension = new DERSequence(subjectAlternativeNames2);
        p10Builder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, subjectAlternativeNamesExtension);//.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAlternativeNames);
        JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("MD5WithRSA");
        ContentSigner signer = csBuilder.build(privateKey);
        PKCS10CertificationRequest thecsr = p10Builder.build(signer);

        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile + "x.csr");
        out.write("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n".getBytes());
        out.write(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(thecsr.getEncoded()).getBytes());
        out.write("\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n".getBytes());
        out.close();
```

The above "seems" to work,  and generates a file /tmp/licensingx.csr as expected.included

Ive been using openssl to verify.   When I use:

> openssl req -in /tmp/licensingx.csr  -text -noout

I was expecting to see something like the following included as part of the output:

> Requested Extensions:
> X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
> EMAIL:clusterid, DNS:127.0.0.1

in fact,  the requested extensions section is missing.   Can anyone suggest something?  We are already using the cluster name as the CN in the subject.

Comment: If you are looking to generate CSR and Download Certificate from web application, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885

Answer (score 0):

after more searching I found I was missing a layer of wrapping.  Result:

```
    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
        new X500Principal("CN=clustername"), publicKey);
    

    ASN1Encodable[] subjectAlternativeNames2 = new ASN1Encodable[] {
            new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, "clusteruid"),
            new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, "127.0.0.1")
    };
    DERSequence subjectAlternativeNamesExtension = new DERSequence(subjectAlternativeNames2);
        
    ExtensionsGenerator extGen = new ExtensionsGenerator();
    extGen.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, true,subjectAlternativeNamesExtension);
        
    
    p10Builder.addAttribute( PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, extGen.generate());
    JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("MD5WithRSA");
    ContentSigner signer = csBuilder.build(privateKey);
    PKCS10CertificationRequest thecsr = p10Builder.build(signer);

    out = new FileOutputStream(outFile + "x.csr");
    out.write("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n".getBytes());
    out.write(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(thecsr.getEncoded()).getBytes());
    out.write("\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n".getBytes());
    out.close();
```