# Signing payload in JS (Frontend) using EC and validating in Python

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

I have a Python backend that generates public/private keys, generates a payload, then needs to get that payload signed by the client (ReactJS or pure JS), which is later verified.

The implementation in Python looks like this:

**Imports**

```py
import json
import uuid

from backend.config import STARTING_BALANCE
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.utils import (
    encode_dss_signature,
    decode_dss_signature
)
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

import base64
import hashlib
```

**Generate keys:**

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.address = hashlib.sha1(str(str(uuid.uuid4())[0:8]).encode("UTF-8")).hexdigest()
        self.private_key = ec.generate_private_key(
            ec.SECP256K1(),
            
            default_backend()
        )

        self.private_key_return = self.private_key.private_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
            encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
        )

        self.public_key = self.private_key.public_key()

        self.serialize_public_key()

    def serialize_public_key():
        """
        Reset the public key to its serialized version.
        """
        self.public_key = self.public_key.public_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
        ).decode('utf-8')
```

**Sign:**

```py
def sign(self, data):
    """
    Generate a signature based on the data using the local private key.
    """
    return decode_dss_signature(self.private_key.sign(
        json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'),
        ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256())
    ))
```

**Verify:**

```py
@staticmethod
def verify(public_key, data, signature):
    """
    Verify a signature based on the original public key and data.
    """
    deserialized_public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        public_key.encode('utf-8'),
        default_backend()
    )

    (r, s) = signature

    try:
        deserialized_public_key.verify(
            encode_dss_signature(r, s),
            json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'),
            ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256())    
        )
        return True
    except InvalidSignature:
        return False
```

What I need now is to load (or even generate) the PEM keys on the client-side, then upon request, sign a JSON payload that can later be verified from the Python backend.

I tried looking into the usage of web cryptography and cryptoJS but had no luck.

I'm okay using another algorithm that is more compatible, but at the very least I need the signing functionality fully working.

I also tried compiling Python to JS using Brython and Pyodide but both could not support all the required packages.

In simple terms, I am looking for the following:

**Generate Payload (Python) -----> Sign Payload (JS) -----> Verify Signature (Python)**

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On SO the recommendation of libraries is off topic. You need a JavaScript library that supports ECDSA for secp256k1. CryptoJS and WebCrypto both don't do that. [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers) does not support asymmetric encryption, [WebCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EcKeyImportParams#properties) does not support secp256k1 (but only secp256r1 aka P-256).

Comment: In my question, I mentioned simply that I tried both and that I am willing to use other algorithms as well. I just could not find any documentation regarding signing data between the 2 languages.

Comment: Could you provide any guidance on the above considering I use  secp256r1  instead? (Seems supported in Python without any major changes to the code).

Comment: Here you can find an example for signing with WebCrypto/ECDSA: https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#ecdsa---sign (as well as other examples e.g. for key generation or key import/export). WebCrypto is a bit cumbersome, so if you have problems, post your code and describe the problem. If NodeJS is also an option, the crypto module of NodeJS is another alternative: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#signsignprivatekey-outputencoding

Comment: One option can be using browser extension on browser side. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers) only supports symmetric encryption and therefore not ECDSA. [WebCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EcKeyGenParams#properties) supports ECDSA, but not secp256k1.
WebCrypto has the advantage that it is supported by all major browsers. Since you can use other curves according to your comment, I will describe a solution with a curve supported by WebCrypto.
Otherwise, [sjcl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EcKeyGenParams#properties) would also be an alternative, a pure JavaScript library that supports ECDSA and especially secp256k1, s.[here](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/ecc.js.html#line341).

WebCrypto is a low level API that provides the functionality you need like key generation, key export and signing. Regarding ECDSA WebCrypto supports the curves P-256 (aka secp256r1), P-384 (aka secp384r1) and p-521 (aka secp521r1). In the following I use P-256.

---

The following JavaScript code generates a key pair for P-256, exports the public key in X.509/SPKI format, DER encoded (so it can be sent to the Python site), and signs a message:

```js
(async () => {

    // Generate key pair
    var keypair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-256", // secp256r1 
        },
        false,
        ["sign", "verify"] 
    );
  
    // Export public key in X.509/SPKI format, DER encoded
    var publicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        "spki", 
        keypair.publicKey 
    );  
    document.getElementById("pub").innerHTML = "Public key: " + ab2b64(publicKey);
  
    // Sign data
    var data = {
        "data_1":"The quick brown fox",
        "data_2":"jumps over the lazy dog"
    }
    var dataStr = JSON.stringify(data) 
    var dataBuf = new TextEncoder().encode(dataStr).buffer
    var signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            hash: {name: "SHA-256"}, 
        },
        keypair.privateKey, 
        dataBuf 
    ); 
    document.getElementById("sig").innerHTML = "Signature: " + ab2b64(signature);
 
})();

// Helper
function ab2b64(arrayBuffer) {
    return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="pub"></p>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="sig"></p>
```

A possible output is:

```
Public key: MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEWzC5lPNifcHNuKL+/jjhrtTi+9gAMbYui9Vv7TjtS7RCt8p6Y6zUmHVpGEowuVMuOSNxfpJYpnGExNT/eWhuwQ==
Signature: XRNTbkHK7H8XPEIJQhS6K6ncLPEuWWrkXLXiNWwv6ImnL2Dm5VHcazJ7QYQNOvWJmB2T3rconRkT0N4BDFapCQ==
```

---

On the Python side a successful verification would be possible with:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.utils import encode_dss_signature
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_public_key
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
import base64
import json

publikKeyDer = base64.b64decode("MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEWzC5lPNifcHNuKL+/jjhrtTi+9gAMbYui9Vv7TjtS7RCt8p6Y6zUmHVpGEowuVMuOSNxfpJYpnGExNT/eWhuwQ==")
data = {
  "data_1":"The quick brown fox",
  "data_2":"jumps over the lazy dog"
}
signature = base64.b64decode("XRNTbkHK7H8XPEIJQhS6K6ncLPEuWWrkXLXiNWwv6ImnL2Dm5VHcazJ7QYQNOvWJmB2T3rconRkT0N4BDFapCQ==")

publicKey = load_der_public_key(publikKeyDer, default_backend())
r = int.from_bytes(signature[:32], byteorder='big')
s = int.from_bytes(signature[32:], byteorder='big')

try:
    publicKey.verify(
        encode_dss_signature(r, s),
        json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8'),
        ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256())    
    )
    print("verification succeeded")
except InvalidSignature:
    print("verification failed")
```

Where, unlike the posted Python code, [`load_der_public_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_der_public_key) is used instead of [`load_pem_public_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_pem_public_key).

Also, WebCrypto returns the signature in IEEE P1363 format, but as a concatenated `ArrayBuffer` r|s, so a conversion of both parts to an integer is necessary to allow a format conversion to ASN.1/DER with `encode_dss_signature()`.

Regarding JSON the separators have to be redefined to the most compact representation (but this depends on the settings on the JavaScript side).

Comment: Amazing! This example was what I've been looking for. Based on the initial comments I had reached a point where it works but verification kept failing. Now I see it's a matter of the format of the data being passed between the 2. Your example works like a charm! Now I'm trying to find a way to store/load the keys in JS (probably will go with IndexedDB + a "text" copy the user can keep). Any ideas/suggestions on that?

Comment: @Waelmas - Key management is a complex topic and worth a separate question. WebCrypto and Indexed DB for keys is discussed e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52488) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/169399).

Comment: Thank you for the info! Will experiment a bit and if I get stuck I might ask a new question.

Comment: Any chance you could shed some light on doing the opposite similarly to the above? What data transformations need to occur on both ends? Shall I post a new question on how to achieve the opposite? (Sign with Python, verify with JS)

Comment: Here is a question with all details @Topaco https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818496/ecsda-sign-with-python-verify-with-js