# Generated CSR has unexpected extension attributes using CertificateEnrollmentManager

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, certificate, csr

I am currently working on generating a Certificate Request using *CertificateEnrollmentManager* from *Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates*. The CSR has been successfully generated but its extensions have different attributes than what I specified in the CertificateRequestProperties.

**This is the request properties:**

```
           var basicConstraint = new CertificateExtension
            {
                ObjectId = Constants.Oids.BASIC_CONSTRAINT,
                IsCritical = false,
                Value = new BasicConstraints(false).GetEncoded()
            };

            var extendedKeyUsage = new CertificateExtension
            {
                ObjectId = Constants.Oids.EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE,
                IsCritical = false,
                Value = new ExtendedKeyUsage(
                    new[] {KeyPurposeID.IdKPClientAuth}
                ).GetEncoded()
            };

            var keyUsage = new CertificateExtension
            {
                ObjectId = Constants.Oids.KEY_USAGE,
                IsCritical = false,
                Value = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature).GetEncoded()
            };
            
            var certificateRequestProperties = new CertificateRequestProperties
            {
                Subject = subject,
                KeyUsages = EnrollKeyUsages.Signing,
                KeyStorageProviderName = microsoftPlatformCryptoProvider,
                Exportable = ExportOption.NotExportable,
                KeyProtectionLevel = keyProtectionLevel,
                KeyAlgorithmName = keyAlgorithmName,
                HashAlgorithmName = hashAlgorithmName,
                FriendlyName = CERTIFICATE_FRIENDLY_NAME,
                Extensions = {basicConstraint, extendedKeyUsage, keyUsage},
                UseExistingKey = false
            };
```

**This is how I generate the SCR:**

```
 var csr = await CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager
            .CreateRequestAsync(certificateRequestProperties);
```

**The CSR is successfully generated but it generated the incorrect extensions:**(Excluded some attributes for brevity)

```
BasicConstraints=ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
ExtendedKeyUsage=ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
KeyUsage=ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
SubjectKeyIdentifier=ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
```

**What is wrong with the generated CSR:**

- It has automatically added **SubjectKeyIdentifier**, but I only specified 3 extensions.
- The `criticality` is NOT as specified in the properties. I specified **false**, but it generated **true**.

My question is, how can I generate the CSR as I specified in the request properties?

PS:

- We can't just modify the received CSR on the server-side.
- I am required to use TPM (MicrosoftPlatformCryptoProvider) for the CSR so private keys are not exportable.

Comment: Check if [Web Browser Certificate Enrollment (CSR Generation) and Certificate Download to Smartcard or USB Token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885) is useful

Comment: The System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificateRequest class doesn’t add anything you don’t ask for. It might do more what you want (though it has no facility to send the CSR anywhere, that’s a problem left to the caller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself and the answer is very simple. It turns out that we can suppress the defaults using the `SuppressedDefaults` property in the request. [Documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificaterequestproperties.suppresseddefaults?view=winrt-22621).

So the request properties will look like:

```
// added new constant
public const string SUBJECT_KEY_IDENTIFIER = "2.5.29.14";

// updated request properties
var certificateRequestProperties = new CertificateRequestProperties
        {
            Subject = subject,
            KeyUsages = EnrollKeyUsages.Signing,
            KeyStorageProviderName = microsoftPlatformCryptoProvider,
            Exportable = ExportOption.NotExportable,
            KeyProtectionLevel = keyProtectionLevel,
            KeyAlgorithmName = keyAlgorithmName,
            HashAlgorithmName = hashAlgorithmName,
            FriendlyName = CERTIFICATE_FRIENDLY_NAME,
            Extensions = {basicConstraint, extendedKeyUsage, keyUsage},
            UseExistingKey = false,
            SuppressedDefaults = { SUBJECT_KEY_IDENTIFIER } 
        };
```

I'm pretty sure I tried this solution before I posted the problem here, but perhaps I just used the wrong OID back then.