# Is it possible to generate PKCS#10 with Javascript SubtleCrypto API?

Tags: javascript, ssl, openssl, webcrypto-api, subtlecrypto

I was able to create PKCS#8 Private & Public RSA keys with the [SubtleCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto). Is it possible to create the very useful PKCS#10 Certificate Signing Request with it as well?

Comment: I've previously had great experiences with pki.js...  https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/

Comment: SubtleCrypto is a higher level API, if it is in there it will be explicit.

Comment: You may use browser extension to generate PKCS#10 CSR. Refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885